# Upgrade angular 4 to 7 http to httpclient

Tags: angular, angular7, ng-upgrade, angular-upgrade

Currently, I am upgrading my Angular project4 using webpack to Angular7. 
I stuck in one step

> Switch from **`HttpModule`** and the **`Http`** service to **`HttpClientModule`** and
> the **`HttpClient`** service. **`HttpClient`** simplifies the default ergonomics
> (You don't need to map to json anymore) and now supports typed return
> values and interceptors.

About this step I need to replace

- **`HttpModule`** => **`HttpClientModule`**
- **`Http`** => **`HttpClient`** 
   
  For updating from **`Http`** => **`HttpClient`**, are there any script to help like 
  `$rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json` or we need to edit manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just change your imports from HttpModule to HttpClientModule and Http to HttpClient

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
```

Comment: Thank you I got it!

Comment: If you believe that this answer is useful please consider to check it as answer. thank you

Comment: @Simonare, In single import statement, you can import both HttpClientModule and HttpClient from '@angular/common/http'. Why we need separate statements for HttpClientModule and HttpClient?

Comment: because they are not going to be in same file :) so please keep them seperate as it was

Comment: Depending on your code, changing just the import statements will likely not be enough. Since some of the API has changed you might also have to change your code that uses the HTTP client.