# Can't upgrade to Angular 8 - running app generates an error from HttpXsrfInterceptor

Tags: angular

After upgrading to Angular8 I get this console error when trying to run the app:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HttpXsrfInterceptor: (?,
>   [object Object]

I am not using `HttpXsrfInterceptor`, and have even tried to disabled it.

Do anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: can you try using `@angular/common/http`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778496/upgrade-angular-4-to-7-angular-http-to-angular-common-http

Comment: Thanks griFlo. I'll check this out later today. I think I'm already doing this though.

Comment: I was actually already using the @angular/common/http library. I had the @angular/http package reference still in my package.json file though, so I just removed it.

I still get the HttpXsrfInterceptor problem though. Really no idea why and I can't find anything useful online.

Answer (score 3):

The [update.angular.io](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0) website states that:

> If you use the legacy HttpModule and the Http service, switch to HttpClientModule and the HttpClient service. HttpClient simplifies the default ergonomics (You don't need to map to json anymore) and now supports typed return values and interceptors. Read more on angular.io

So you should remove your dependency on the `@angular/http` package, and move on to the new way of doing HTTP requests - possibly adapting your codebase accordingly.

The official doc for the "new way" is: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Thanks Mic, yes I had already done that but had left the package in my package.json file.

Comment: I'm still stuck with this error, but it's not related to Angular 8. It seems to be to do with core-js.

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue was because of core-js so not related to Angular or HTTP service.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in Angular 7.  I've the error in JIT but not in AOT.  Could you detail your solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, for now I've just kept core-js on the latest in version 2.
I'm planning on removing core-js completely as it doesn't seem necessary in the latest Angular 9 app created by the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and we find the mistake.  The build was working in AOT but not in JIT.
Somewhere in our code we had this import:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
```

It has been moved to polyfills.